# Garbage collection of an object containing a thread with an infinte loop

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Lets say I have a class that is doing something like:

```
 public class Foo
 {
     private bool _forceStop = false;
     private Queue<object> queue;
     private void ProcessInBackground()
     {
          while(!forceStop )
          {
              Moniter.Enter(queue);
              while(!_forceStop && queue.Count == 0)Moniter.Wait(queue);
              object data = null;                 
              if (!_forceStop)
                 data = queue.Dequeue(); 
              Moniter.Exit(queue);

              if (data != null)
                 processData(data);
           }
      }

      ...
  }
```

If an object of class Foo is no longer being used and _forceStop is never set to true in that object and assuming ProcessInBackground has been called, will it be collected?

Edit: Resolved, ambiguities added thread safety. Sorry when I wrote the example I just made up a scenario.

Comment: @DavidB - 4 ways to read a question. Programming itself is quite exact.

Comment: @David hardly clear when the OP doesn't specify **which object** they mean...

Comment: You should really define "the object" and "that method" so that it is clear exactly what you're talking about. While it may seem obvious to you, it's clearly not obvious to the experts answering the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Like Marc, I'm assuming you're referring to the object on which you called `ProcessInBackground`. I'm also assuming that `queue` is a field.)

No - you're still referring to `queue`, which means that field in the object *will* be read, which means the containing object can't be garbage collected.

Note that just because a method is running in the object does *not* prevent garbage collection - the garbage collector only cares whether there's any possibility of either the reference itself being used, or a field within the object being read. Demo code to show that:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class OddFinalizer   
{
    int field;

    public OddFinalizer(int field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }

    ~OddFinalizer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OddFinalizer");
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In loop before last access...");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();            
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Field value: {0}", field);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In loop after last access...");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new OddFinalizer(10).Work();
    }
}
```

Results (compiled with /o+, *not* run in a debugger):

```
In loop before last access..
In loop before last access..
In loop before last access..
In loop before last access..
In loop before last access..
Field value: 10
In loop after last access...
OddFinalizer
In loop after last access...
In loop after last access...
In loop after last access...
In loop after last access...
```

Comment: Assuming there wasn't any I/O involved, and all reads and writes were restricted to fields within that same object, would they still keep the object from being collected?

Comment: @Vlad: Yes - the GC doesn't care about what's going to *happen* to the values of the fields - just that they're being read.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `object data` will be collected (assuming `processData()` doesn't put it into a list). 
The GC can handle (managed) threads, the world would end if it couldn't.

But your code is *not* thread-safe, your DeQueueing after you give up the lock.

A suggestion to improve:

```
//untested
private bool _forceStop = false;
private object _locker = new object();  // better not depend on queue here

private void ProcessInBackground()
{
    while(true)
    {
       // Moniter.Enter(queue);
       lock(_locker)
       {       
          while(!_forceStop && queue.Count == 0)
            Moniter.Wait(_locker);

          //Moniter.Exit(queue);
          if (_forceStop) break;

          object data = queue.Dequeue(); 
       }
       processData(data);
    }
}
```

Edit:

On second read this is about the containing object. Which is of course kept from collection by the thread.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on where the queue is?

Comment: @vlad henk is right - you should hold the lock to enqueue or dequeue here

Comment: @Marc I wasn't referring to thread safety. I was referring to the fact that if some other object has a reference to the same queue, then stopping the thread and collecting it would change the semantics of the program.

Comment: Unless some strange optimizations happen, this object shouldn't get collected until the appdomain shuts down. The thread still refers to fields of the containing object.

Comment: @Vlad thread safety is relevant. If he had no memory barriers inside his loop, the compiler can decide that `_forceStop` and `queue.Count` will never change inside the loop and thus optimize your break condition out. But I think you have implicit memory barriers in there which safe him.

Comment: @Henk, wouldn't locking on "locker" be the same as treating the queue as lock since they are both contained in the class? Note: I resolved some ambiguities in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "the object" you mean the instance that owns the method, then if a thread is executing the ProcessInBackground method, then that instance is rooted by the thread (it is arg0, and you are using fields from it in the loop). So no, it will not be collected.

If the "the object" you mean "data", then all but the most recent are *certainly* eligible. The most recent may depend on the compiler config (did it eliminate the local?) and the CLI (is it checking locals that aren't read?). I'd say "it will probably be eligible, in release/optimised; probably not in debug/unoptimised".

Comment: I assumed it was about `object data = ...`

Comment: @Henk I added both in an edit. See also my note on debug - any thoughts on that?

Comment: Have a look at my answer for an example of an instance method where the finalizer is called while an instance method is running - I'm assuming that's enough of a demonstration of GC eligibility :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I read the question the same way as Marc did, given the phrase "If the object containing that method"

Comment: @MarcGravell: Righto, much better :)

Answer (score 1):

> and _forceStop is never set to true, will the object be collected?

No.

An object can't be garbage collected while one of its methods is on a callstack of a thread.  The callstack has a reference to the object.

In this case, `ProcessInBackground` is a method on a callstack of a thread.

---

Jon's answer corrects my answer - garbage collector works when it's confident no more references will be used, including the `this` reference.  That means that an object may be collected while it has a method on the callstack (this method may be using other methods, but not using any of this instance's own members).

In my own code, I have no finalizers.  I have few objects that I care when they get collected.  When I expect these to get collected, they aren't on the callstack at that point.  If they are collected while they are on the callstack, because .net thinks that's a good thing, no problem by me.

I don't think that detail would change how I should write any code, so I'm going to choose to continue writing code as though my wrong fact above were true, while being slightly mindful of it's wrongness.  If my situation is similiar to yours, you may be able to do so as well.

Comment: Ah - sigh, I suppose so.  Well, I don't want to leave false info up.  Will have to ponder an edit to incorporate this new fact.